# Airflow BigQueryOperator: how to save query result in a partitioned Table?

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

I have a simple DAG

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryOperator

with DAG(dag_id='my_dags.my_dag') as dag:

    start = DummyOperator(task_id='start')

    end = DummyOperator(task_id='end')
    sql = """
             SELECT *
             FROM 'another_dataset.another_table'
          """
    bq_query = BigQueryOperator(bql=sql,
                            destination_dataset_table='my_dataset.my_table20180524'),
                            task_id='bq_query',
                            bigquery_conn_id='my_bq_connection',
                            use_legacy_sql=False,
                            write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
                            create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
                            query_params={})
    start >> bq_query >> end
```

When executing the `bq_query` task the SQL query gets saved in a sharded table. I want it to get saved in a daily partitioned table. In order to do so, I only changed `destination_dataset_table` to `my_dataset.my_table$20180524`. I got the error below when executing the `bq_task`:

```
Partitioning specification must be provided in order to create partitioned table
```

How can I specify to BigQuery to save query result to a daily partitioned table ? my first guess has been to use `query_params` in `BigQueryOperator` 
but I didn't find any example on how to use that parameter.

**EDIT:**

I'm using `google-cloud==0.27.0` python client ... and it's the one used in Prod :(

Comment: Doesn't `CREATE TABLE... PARTITION BY ... AS SELECT...` work?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard I don't think it's going to work, because the DAG is going to be executed each day. With `CREATE ...` the table will be created after each execution. I just want to create a new partition not the whole table.

Answer (score 9):

You first need to create an Empty partitioned destination table. Follow instructions here: [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions#creating_an_empty_partitioned_table_with_a_schema_definition) to create an empty partitioned table

and then run below airflow pipeline again.
You can try code:

```py
import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryOperator
today_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")
table_name = 'my_dataset.my_table' + '$' + today_date
with DAG(dag_id='my_dags.my_dag') as dag:
    start = DummyOperator(task_id='start')
    end = DummyOperator(task_id='end')
    sql = """
         SELECT *
         FROM 'another_dataset.another_table'
          """
    bq_query = BigQueryOperator(bql=sql,
                        destination_dataset_table={{ params.t_name }}),
                        task_id='bq_query',
                        bigquery_conn_id='my_bq_connection',
                        use_legacy_sql=False,
                        write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
                        create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
                        query_params={'t_name': table_name},
                        dag=dag
                        )
start >> bq_query >> end
```

So what I did is that I created a dynamic table name variable and passed to the BQ operator.

Comment: I'm not getting the error anymore: `the Task exited with return code 0`. But, the result table is not created, I don't see it in BigQuery. Weird

Comment: You first need to create an Empty partitioned destination table. Follow instructions here: `https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions#creating_an_empty_partitioned_table_with_a_schema_definition` to create an empty partitioned table

Comment: or you can use `BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator()` to create an empty table with partition by setting `time_partitioning` parameter

Comment: the thing is I don't want to specify the schema. I don't think using `BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator()` without any schema is alowed. As in the BigQuery UI, creating an empty daily-partitioned table and without any field results in an error

Comment: `schema` in `BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator()` is an optional parameter. Check [this](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.py), 
We built this operator keeping in mind that we don't want to specify any schema. 
If you check the doc string for `BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator ` class --> 
`Creates a new, empty table in the specified BigQuery dataset,
    optionally with schema.`

Comment: example : `time_partitioning={'type': 'DAY', 'field': 'test_field', 'expirationMs': 1000}`

Comment: This feature was not merged in the previous version, I have asked my friend to check if he can merge this in current Airflow. Good news he merged the feature in the current version. First, you need to install the current version then run the above example.

Comment: Thanks @gruby, the version that I'm using is 1.9.0. I think it's the last stable version (according the [repo](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/releases)). How do I update my version to get the last features ?

Comment: This is expensive if you have a lot of data.  Why not use the free copy bigquery operator instead? https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_to_bigquery.py

Comment: I have same doubt, But this is for BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator. When we are creating a table using operator. We need to specify table_id='Emp_7 in parameter which is the table name.My question is If Table already exist so it should not create a table, If table not exist then only it should be created. How we can do this ??

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that I don't have access to the new version of google cloud python API, the prod is using version [0.27.0](https://gcloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/bigquery/usage.html).
So, to get the job done, I made something bad and dirty:

- saved the query result in a sharded table, let it be `table_sharded`
- got `table_sharded`'s schema, let it be `table_schema`
- saved  `" SELECT * FROM dataset.table_sharded"` query to a partitioned table providing `table_schema`

All this is abstracted in one single operator that uses a hook. The hook is responsible of creating/deleting tables/partitions, getting table schema and running queries on BigQuery.

Have a look at the [code](https://gist.github.com/MassyB/be4555a5fc8e6c433766d71e9d760f91). If there is any other solution, please let me know.

Comment: Can you use a (free) bq copy table command instead of the query?

Answer (score 0):

Using BigQueryOperator you can pass time_partitioning parameter which will create ingestion-time partitioned tables

```
bq_cmd = BigQueryOperator (
            task_id=                    "task_id",
            sql=                        [query],
            destination_dataset_table=  destination_tbl,
            use_legacy_sql=             False,
            write_disposition=          'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
            time_partitioning=          {'time_partitioning_type':'DAY'},
            allow_large_results=        True,
            trigger_rule=               'all_success',
            query_params=               query_params,
            dag=                        dag
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator

DEFAULT_DAG_ARGS = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'retries': 2,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=10),
    'project_id': Variable.get('gcp_project'),
    'zone': Variable.get('gce_zone'),
    'region': Variable.get('gce_region'),
    'location': Variable.get('gce_zone'),
}

with DAG(
    'test',
    start_date=datetime(2019, 1, 1),
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup=False,
    default_args=DEFAULT_DAG_ARGS) as dag:

    bq_query = BigQueryOperator(
        task_id='create-partition',
        bql="""SELECT
                * 
                FROM
                `dataset.table_name`""",   -- table from which you want to pull data
        destination_dataset_table='project.dataset.table_name' + '$' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d'),             -- Auto partitioned table in Bq 
        write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
        create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
        use_legacy_sql=False,
    )
```

I recommend to use Variable in Airflow and create all fields and use in DAG.
By above code, partition will be added in Bigquery table for Todays date.